# 32-bit of precision, what does it mean?

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I'm reading a book about OPENGL ES development. I came across to this sentence.

> A float in Java has 32 bits of precision, while a byte has 8 bits of precision. This might seem like an obvious point to make, but there are 4 bytes in every float.

What exactly does that mean? Is this important to know in Android game development?

Comment: Do you know what 'byte', 'bit', and 'precision' mean?

Comment: This is important to know in overall software development

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: In game development, the first rule is to avoid floating point operations and use integer whereever you can.

Comment: Its basically the number of decimal places that the value can hold. **BUT** they are binary decimal places not decimal. A double has twice as many `1`s or `0`s to hold its data so can be more precise (the whole thing is complicated by the way floating point numbers are held to allow then to scale but thats the basic idea)

Comment: @guntramBlohm avoiding them is ok but before you avoid them you should know what they do, in case that you need them one day.

Comment: "Is this important to know in android game development?" It's important to know always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What exactly does that mean?

1 Byte=  8 Bit

4 Byte= 32 Bit

---

**1Bit** can have **2 conditions** 0 or 1

**2Bits** can have **2² conditions** 00 , 01, 10 and 11

---

Ok, now it comes to the hard point

If your **accuracy** should be **+/-0.5** **the maximum size** that your number can be is **2^23.** Now you may ask yourself and what is if i got a number that is larger than this? *Anything that is bigger than this is bigger than 0.5.*

(Single-Precission /32 Bit)

---

> Is this important to know in android game development?

It is important, that you **understood the basic concept** behind this in nearly any programming language.

Take a look at that simple program, if you understood the output, that is all you need to know, **first of all**

```
public class DoubleError
{
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             double x = 1.1;
             double y = 0.1;
             System.out.println("X is: " + x);
             System.out.println("Y is: " + y);
             System.out.println("X+Y is: " + (x + y));

       }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Oh, and to totally crash your head,

here some more points that you should know:

Half- Precision  = 16 Bit

Single-Precision = 32 Bit

Double-Precision = 64 Bit

---

EDIT 2:

Oh, and if you want to understand anything, check out this: [IEEE_754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

Comment: @rootpanthera if you did not do it yet, i really suggest you to try the example and figure it out ;) glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

the sentence from this book does not mean anything, it seems to be simply wrong.

32 bit float has a precision of 23 bits, not of 32.

Comment: The float might have 32 bit precision, but the significand does not. It seems your statement is missing context.

Comment: the context was "A float has 32 bits of precision", and the precision of a floating point number IS the length of the significand. what else could be interesting than the decimal representation?

Comment: The exponent. There's two precisions (as you know). I mention this nitpicky thing, not for you, but because the OP and possibly others might not be of our level of understanding. Concluding it might be wise to explain why 23 bits for the significand and where the other bits go.