# javascript - variable as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

How does JavaScript 'store' the s variable as an array?  why wouldn't the s variable will be overwritten in this line`"s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]); "`

```js
var number = prompt("fibonacci")

var fibo = function(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return [0, 1];
  } else {
    var s = fibo(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    return s;
  }
}
console.log(fibo(number));
```

BUT HOW IS IT STORING THE VARIABLE AS AN ARRAY?

Comment: Read about [push method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) , it ADDS to an array, so s.push() is just adding, never removing.

Comment: Just because it's an easier way to calculate Fibonacci value. Check Array behaviour: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: `push` appends a value to `s` array; this value is evaluated before `push` executes. So, it changes `s`, but it doesn't overwrite it, it just extends it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fibonacci Sequence (JS) - Sum of Even Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085932/fibonacci-sequence-js-sum-of-even-numbers)

Comment: This is a beginner programming problem, not a problem with understanding Fibonacci...

Answer (score 1):

```
return [0, 1]; // Creates the array
...
var s = fibo(n - 1); // Assigns array to s (s references array)
```

`s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);`

only push writes to the array (left hand side)

other operations on the same line only read from it (right hand side)

I recommend you start with the basics and later start with recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Push doesn't overwrite the array, rather just adding the new item to the end of it.

```
var s = [0, 1];

var lastItem = s[s.length - 1]; // 1
var itemBeforeLast = s[s.length - 2]; // 0
var sum = lastItem + itemBeforeLast; // 1

s.push(sum); // s is now [0, 1, 1]
```